# Why does {}|[]|()|str|set|etc. > n equals True in python2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison

I noticed this when trying to compare:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    pass
```

but I had done this and still was True (Took me some time to find the bug.):

```
if sys.argv >= 2: # This is True!!!
    pass
```

Here are some more examples:

```
>>> {} > 2
True
>>> [] > 2
True
>>> () > 2
True
>>> set > 2
True
>>> str > 2
True
>>> enumerate > 2
True
>>> __builtins__ > 2
True
>>> class test:
...     pass
... 
>>> test
<class __main__.test at 0xb751417c>
>>> test > 2
True
```

In python3.x it causes a TypeError.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing different *types*. In Python 2, types are ordered relative to one another by their *name*, and numeric types are *always* ordered before everything else.

This was introduced to allow sorting of heterogeneous lists, containing different types of data.

Python 3 rectifies this somewhat surprising behaviour, there comparing types (to numbers or to one another) is always an error unless specifically allowed by custom comparison hooks:

```
>>> {} > 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() > int()
>>> class Foo:
...     def __gt__(self, other):
...         if isinstance(other, int):
...             return True
... 
>>> Foo() > 3
True
```